# How to put an output in a new line in an output text file

Tags: java, jtable

So I am a noob in java and I need help. I am creating an attendance program for my project. So if i happen to click the "submit" button, the program asks the user to enter a file name, after you hit "OK" it creates a text file in the given file path, the problem is, my output goes on a straight line and i don't know what to do, i've tried putting so many newLine"\n"'s in my codes but it doesn't work.

```
if (listen.getActionCommand().equals("Submit")) {

    final234();

    File dir = new File("D://blablabla");
    dir.mkdir();
    String name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the file: ");
    File f = new File(dir, name1 + ".txt");

    try {
        if (f.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("A new File has been created.");

            op = "";
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(pw);
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    op += (table.getValueAt(i, j) + " ");
                }
                op = "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(op);

            bw.write(op + "\n");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `for` statement ends with `op="\n";` (maybe you meant `op+="\n"`) so I am surprised that you actually write something else than newlines in the file.

Comment: Instead of you using \n, try to use: System.lineSeparator()

Comment: As @arnaud said, use  `op += System.lineSeparator()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be having trouble because the newline character on **Windows** and **Unix** based system represented differently.
On **Windows** it's `"\r\n"`, while in **Unix** it's indeed `"\n"`.
The best way to ensure you're using the right character is to use `System.lineSeparator()` which will return the right character for you.

Also:

```
op = "\n";
```

Means you just initialize the variable with "\n" and override its previous content.

You can do `op += System.lineSeparator();` every time you want to add a new line to the current String.

Comment: @Maximus if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.